# Google maps doesn't load in Jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps

Its a very old question and I've tried all solutions available to go pass it without any success. I tried all the accepted answers without any success which makes me believe that I must be doing something wrong.

Below are the details:

- gem **gmaps4rails** 1.5.6 (https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails)
- Rails 3.2.19
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Jquery 1.10

Code looks something like this:

```
    // tab code example
        <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">Tab3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab4">Tab4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab5">Tab5</a></li>


        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Map1</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Map2</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Map3</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Map4</h2>
        </div>
         <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
            <h2>Map5</h2>
        </div>
// tab example ends
```

I've already tried these answers:

[Loading Google Maps in jQuery tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819027/loading-google-maps-in-jquery-tab)
[Google Maps Not Working in jQuery Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458215/google-maps-not-working-in-jquery-tabs)
[Google Map in Bootstrap Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635903/google-map-in-bootstrap-tab)
[Google Maps and jQuery Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014156/google-maps-and-jquery-tabs)
[Google Maps unable to fully load in jquery nav-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207481/google-maps-unable-to-fully-load-in-jquery-nav-tab)
[Google Maps, Rails and Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212009/google-maps-rails-and-jquery)
[Google Maps and jQuery Tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014156/google-maps-and-jquery-tabs)

Comment: suggest you create a demo that replicates your problem. Did you set the map container dimensions? Using the maps resize method should work as does approach of changing the content to display off screen.

Comment: Sorry guys..Yeah i saw the formatting going completely wrong

Comment: Does it feel better now?

Comment: @charlietfl :- Yeah tried doing that and then call resize method. Didn't work for me

Comment: Well nobody can help if you don't show the code you tried that isn't working. Create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

[OP's solution converted to answer below]

Finally what worked for me was including this in view specific js, so in my view.js i have :-

```
 $( "#tabs" ).bind( "click", function() {
        Gmaps.loadMaps();
    });
```

In view.html.erb :-

```
<%= gmaps(..)%>
```